# What does $E^{2}$ mean in this context?

Tags: notation

Let $P_{i} \in E^{2}$ be the vector location of demand point $i, i = 1,..., n$

What is $E^{2}$?

Found it in a journal paper but not sure if I can link it.

Comment: Can you at least say what the paper is (title, journal, year, page)? My guess would be: $E^2$ is the plane, two-dimensional Euclidean space, $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Most probably Eucliean two space.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat It is "The hub location and routing problem" by 
Turgut Aykin. European Journal of Operational Research. 1995. Page 206.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably $\mathbb{R}^2$.

---

Indeed, on the first page of the [article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377221793E0173U#) the author says

> The hub location problem on the plane $E^2 $ ...

Comment: $E\,$ for “Euclidean”.

Comment: Guess I shouldn't rely on Ctrl+F. Thanks, can't believe I missed that. Good to know it's equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ though.